# Select case multiple conditions string and long

Tags: vba

How can i improve the following working code?

I would like to be able to join the "Select Case True" with the normal "Select Case" conditions

```
With w.Sheets("test")
    For i = n To 10 Step -1
        Select Case .Cells(i, 1)
            Case 10111,23232,98076,41324
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End Select
        Select Case True
            Case .Cells(i, 1) Like "A*"
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End Select
    Next i
End With
```

Thank You

Comment: With your last edit, you invalidated the current answer. Something we don't take lightly on Code Review. However, reverting the question back to it's original state would make it off-topic, since example code is off-topic. For among others *exactly* the reason you just ran into, the answer was less helpful to you because you didn't provide the code you actually use. Please look at the [help/on-topic] and make sure the current code is actual code.

Comment: do you not consider confidential data? a lot of people cannot post actual code for this reason so i have to change it slightly

Comment: Confidential data shouldn't be posted. You can make modifications shifting the data a bit if that has no implications for the code involved, but you can't simplify it like you did.

Comment: then please advise me as to which community this belongs in. i cant post this on overflow - that's for assisting others with code problems.

Comment: @user1 How is "10111,23232,98076,41324" possibly confidential? Your question does belong here, but please avoid simplifying your code in the future.

Comment: Luckily the answer has now been edited to match your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. If the list is reasonably finite (two or three elements), then you could make it a bit spaghetti and say

```
        Select Case True
            Case .Cells(i, 1) Like "A*"
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Case .Cells(i, 1) = 10111
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Case .Cells(i, 1) = 23232
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            ...
        End Select
```

But this has the terrible disadvantage of getting nasty very quickly. Other options:

```
With w.Sheets("test")
    For i = n To 10 Step -1
        Select Case .Cells(i, 1)
            Case 10111,23232,98076,41324
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Case Else
                If .Cells(i, 1) Like "A*" Then
                    .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
        End Select
    Next i
End With
```

By the way, calling your workbook just plain `w` is quite a poor variable naming, choose something more explicit and informative like myImportantWorkbookOnThisDay or whatever. I like the camelCase, but you can choose any casing you like. Just some revealing name.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. i will accept. Whilst it works, i dont think mixing Switches and If statements makes for easily understandable code. I think having the seperate TRUE condition allows us to accept that select cannot accept 2 different data types in one condition, so we must seperate them. Appreciate the input! and will be more mindful of how i post code in the future :)

Comment: @user1, unfortunately VBA has a bit stiff `Select Case` statement. You can evaluate only one condition type. You give a _value_ and the `Select Case` will run the `Case` that matches this _value_, both on its type and its evaluation. If you give it a `Boolean` (`True`), it will run the `Case` that evaluates to this boolean. If you give it a `String`, it will run the `Case` that evaluates to a `String` of the same contents. Give it a `Long`, and it will run the `Case` that evaluates to a `Long` of the same value... You get the idea :)

Comment: yep indeed! i wonder if there is a function that can handle multiple data types